# .htaccess redirect root to cgi-bin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cgi-bin

I'm working with a school that requires Wordpress to be installed in the cgi-bin.

I'd like to put an htaccess in the public_html folder so it redirects to the cgi-bin.

Example:

Redirect from /dept/my-dept/ to /dept/my-dept/cgi-bin?

Also is it possible to "hide" the cgi-bin from the URL altogether? Obviously, I can't move the Wordpress files from cgi-bin to the /my-dept/ root directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /cgi-bin/
```

...If you have mod_rewrite installed

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

You could also do a 301 redirect like:

```
redirect 301 / /cgi-bin/
```

...But cgi-bin will still be visible with the second method.